# Chandra grahan & Kojagiri pournima

Tags: rituals, astrology

The Chandra Grahan and Kojagiri Poornima seems to coincide at the night of October 28 to early morning of 29 Oct. Is it correct?
What rituals can we perform at this time?

Comment: For the year 2023